# gcloud-ml doesn't create savedModel

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

Using the gcloudml-examples templates i created a new model. 
Running local in gcloud shell with command line

```
gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name=trainer.task  --package- 
  path=./trainer -- --train-files="gs://bucket- 
  ml/data/treinamento/train/part
  *.csv" --eval-files="gs://bucket-ml/data/treinamento/test/part*.csv" 
  -- job-dir="gs://bucket-ml/data/treinamento/modelo"
```

everything work's fine.GCloud-ml creates several checkpoints at ..treinamento/modelo and creates a folder in it with savedModel

the problem is when I submit to gcloud with

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "JobName123" \
  --job-dir "gs://bucket-ml/data/export" \
  --packages="gs://bucket-ml/modelo/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"\
  --module-name="trainer.task"\
  --scale-tier=BASIC \
  --region us-east1 \
  -- --train-files="gs://bucket-ml/data/treinamento/train/part*.csv"\
    --eval-files="gs://bucket-ml/data/treinamento/test/part*.csv"\
    --verbosity="DEBUG"
```

gcloud-ml read train and eval files, creates checkpoint just like local mode, but doesn't create folder and savedModel

and ends with no error. 
The code is exactly the same. Just package the trainer with python setup.py sdis. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ‘packages’, could you user ‘package-path’ like the example provided in [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction#cloud-train-single) document. Also, monitor the [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction#inspect_the_stackdriver_logs) logs for any warnings or errors as well as [training jobs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/monitor-training), they might provide more information.